# Kidney transplant and adrenal glands

Tags: anatomy, kidney, surgery

When a kidney is transplanted from a donor to a recepient does the surgery occur keeping the donor's adrenal gland intact over the kidney or is the kidney minus the adrenal gland over it transplanted to the recepient?

Comment: I called and spoke the University of Kentucky Kidney Transplant Center, and asked this question. They said that the de facto source for kidney transplant information & procedure is available at [UNOS.org](https://www.unos.org/transplantation/), and that any information that any transplant center is going to provide the patient would be from that site; though, some procedures and policies may vary from center to center. I also did another search online, and was able to find forums for patients, and there are people who claim of having received, and not received, the adrenal gland.